# How to find pandas columns with one or more negative values

Tags: python, pandas

If I want find out all the features in a pandas dataframe with at least one zero value then I can use the following command.

```
df.isin([0]).sum()
```

That's simple and elegant. What's the equivalent of that to find out features with negative values.

There seems to be no straightforward way to find out all the columns in a pandas dataframe with at least one negative value. Can you please help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[df<0].sum()`, would give you the sum across along all the columns. And further just add one more `sum` to convert to `df[df<0].sum().sum()`. For computing the sum of all the negative values. And if you want to find which columns have value `<0`, just check the values returned by `df[df<0].sum()`

Comment: Unfortunately it prompts me with TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Its because you have string values in the columns. You might have to either typecast them to `int` or just select the required columns with `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `apply`:

```
(df < 0).apply(lambda x: any(x))
```

The apply function will run the built-in `any` function column-wise, which performs as an OR function on all values in column.
Note that this should be **faster** than summing in this case.

Comment: I get the following error  TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It means that your DataFrame contains strings and not only numbers (in this case, int). If that is the case you need to decide how you handle strings. Do you wish to ignore them?

Comment: i would like to ignore them,what then?

Answer (score 0):

This will count the observations with negative values in each column:

```
df1[df1<0].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another way:

```
r, c = np.where(df < 0)
df.columns[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help.

Here is the final solution I worked out.

```
numerical_columns = [c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype.name != 'object']

df[df[numerical_columns] < 0].count() # to deal with int to str conversion problem
```